# How to create an object in java with some fields located in a driver class?

Tags: java, arraylist, hierarchy

I am still pretty new with Java so don't hesitate if you think I am wildly off here...

I have a Java program with multiple object blueprint classes, a menu class, and a driver class. The driver class calls menu. In the menu class, I create a customer object while instantiating only 1 of it's 4 fields. The field is unique ID field. I want to get the other 3 fields from an ArrayList located in the driver class. How can I choose a customer object from an ArrayList in a separate class?

The first Object I am trying to create.

```
public class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;

    public static int count = 100;

public Customer(String name, String address, String phone) {

    this.id = count;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
            count++;
}
```

}

Reservation has a Customer

```
public class Reservation {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private Customer customer;
private Flight flight;
private int partySize;
private double reservationCost;



final private double FIRST_CLASS_COST = 850.00;
final private double ECONOMY_COST = 450.00;

public Reservation(Customer customer, Flight flight, int partySize, double reservationCost) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.flight = flight;
    this.partySize = partySize;
    this.reservationCost = reservationCost;
}
```

In the driver class, called AirlineDriver, there is an ArrayList of Customers. In the code below, how would I create a Customer object to then create a Reservation if I need to get one of the Customers in the ArrayList in the driver?

```
public class Menu {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public Reservation createReservation() {

    Customer cust = new Customer();
    Flight flight;
    Reservation reservation;

    System.out.println("Are you a returning customer? (Y or N)");
    String w = scan.nextLine();
    while (!"Y".equals(w) || !"y".equals(w) || !"N".equals(w) || !"n".equals(w)) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect key, please enter Y for Yes, and N for No.");
        w = scan.nextLine();
    }
    if (w.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || w.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.println("Welcome back and thank you for flying with us.");
        System.out.println("What is your Customer ID?");
        int custID = scan.nextInt();

    }
```

If the customer already exists, they are already in this ArrayList.

```
public class AirlineDriver {

private static Scanner files;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Customer> cust = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have declared all getter method in `Customer` class. Because, I didn't declared. You need to iterate through the `ArrayList<Customer>`

```
for(Customer custom : cust)
{
   // call all your getter method from Customer class.
   String customerName = custom.getName();
}
```

Comment: AirlineDriver is a menu-driven program. How can I iterate through the ArrayList if I am creating the customer in a separate class? Do I need to move the Menu class into AirlineDriver?

Comment: @miler4salem you need to get the populated list to iterate